# Trying to output the columns for a collection of Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

My controller:

```
def testing
  @models = [User, Products]
end
```

testing.html.erb:

```
<% @models.each do |m| %>
  <%= render partial: "details", model: m %>
<% end %>
```

_details.html.erb:

```
<% @m.columns.each do |c| %>
  <li><%= c.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

I am getting the error:

```
undefined method `columns' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm not sure why this doesn't works.

My code worked fine when I was using a single Active Record Model, now I want to be able to do the same thing with an Array of Models, so I broke my template out into a partial so I can loop through my models and output this information.

What seems to be the problem?

**Update**

Strange because this works fine:

```
<% @models.each do |m| %>
    <%= m.columns %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing local variable `model` to your _detail view partial and calling instance variable `@m`. Change your code in the testing.html.erb to

```
<% @models.each do |m| %>
  <%= render partial: "details", locals: { model: m } %>
<% end %>
```

and _details.html.erb to

```
<% model.columns.each do |c| %>
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<% @models.each do |m| %>
  <%= render partial: "details", locals: {model: m} %>
<% end %>
```

And in the _details.html.erb:

```
<% model.columns.each do |c| %>
  <li><%= c.name %></li>
<% end %>
```